# how to iterate over a list containing multiple list and tuple

Tags: python, list

Iterate over a list conataining multiple list and tuple

```
pixel_coord=[]

[[(7261, 8764), (7288, 8764)], [(4421, 8937), (4448, 8937)]
```

increase 7261 by 7, decrease 7288 by 7 for the whole list.

I tried iterating list but don't know how to proceed

```
for p in range(len(pixel_coord)):
for i in range(4):
    print( pixel_coord[p][i][0] + 1)
    print( pixel_coord[p][i][1] - 1)
    i+=1
p+=1
```

Comment: can you check your indentation? also, you may want to read up on some basic tutorials for python on how the loops work, `p` does not contain indexes. Also, do not use the `list` for variable name

Comment: is your list always having the same size? Can't it be longer or shorter?

Comment: the list contains 500 tuples and increase 7261 by 7, decrease 7288 is an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple iteration & `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
lst = [[(7261, 8764), (7288, 8764)], [(4421, 8937), (4448, 8937)]]
result = []
for i in lst:
    temp = []
    for ind, (x,y) in enumerate(i):
        if ind == 0:
            temp.append((x+7, y))
        else:
            temp.append((x-7, y))
    result.append(temp)

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[(7268, 8764), (7281, 8764)], [(4428, 8937), (4441, 8937)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a= [[(7261, 8764), (7288, 8764)], [(4421, 8937), (4448, 8937)]]

def fun(a):
    k=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if i%2==0:
            tmp=(a[i][0]+7,a[i][1])
            k.append(tmp)
        elif i%2==1:
            tmp=(a[i][0]-7,a[i][1])
            k.append(tmp)
    return k

sol= list(map(lambda x:fun(x), a))
print(sol)
```

output

```
[[(7268, 8764), (7281, 8764)], [(4428, 8937), (4441, 8937)]
```

Comment: the inner list containing tuple that is first tuple x co-ordinate +7 and second tuple x co-ordinate -7

Comment: my output should be [[(7268, 8764), (7281, 8764)], [(4428, 8937), (4441, 8937)]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can loop through your list of lists of tuples:

```
  temp = []
  for outerListIndex in range(len(pixel_coord)):
     for innerListIndex in range(len(pixel_coord[outerListIndex])):
        tupleElement1 = pixel_coord[outerListIndex][innerListIndex][0]
        tupleElement2 = pixel_coord[outerListIndex][innerListIndex][1]

        # Do your operations on the elements here
        temp.append( (tupleElement1 + 7, tupleElement2 - 7) )

  pixel_coord = temp
```

Once you properly name the variables your code becomes much easier to understand.